# How do you reopen messages.json in Sublime Text (3)?

Tags: json, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, package-control

I read *packagecontrol.io's* [doc](https://packagecontrol.io/docs/messaging)
regarding messages.json, but what I'm referring to is the file tab that sublime text typically displays upon a new package install. It appears as a continuous roll of installation notes throughout multiple installations. It appears that this is a feed of the individual **messages.json** files displayed when the packages are downloaded. Is there a way to open the unified file that displays messages from multiple packages? Or is there a more common way to access these package files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking about are the `install` and `release` messages pointed to by those keys inside `messages.json`. For example, from one of my packages,

```js
{
    "install": "messages/install.txt",
    "1.2.1": "messages/1.2.1.txt",
    "1.3.0": "messages/1.3.0.txt",
    "1.3.1": "messages/1.3.1.txt",
    "1.4.2": "messages/1.4.2.txt",
    "2.0.1": "messages/2.0.0.txt",
    "2.1.1": "messages/2.1.0.txt",
    "2.2.0": "messages/2.2.0.txt",
    "2.2.1": "messages/2.2.1.txt"
}
```

Whenever someone installs the package for the first time, Package Control prints the contents of `messages/install.txt` to that new view you mentioned. It will also print the file corresponding to the *current* release, which is a "release" tagged on Github. If I were to go and release 2.3.0, for example, and not update `messages.json`, no update message would be printed telling users I'd pushed out a new version. In some cases this is desirable, in case I had to quickly push out a point release to fix some stupid mistake I made in a major (or minor) release, not that I've ever done that before :) But, in most cases, I want to keep users up to date on development, so I'll write a message for them in a new file, and add an appropriate key and value to `messages.json`.

> Is there a way to open the unified file that displays messages from multiple packages? Or is there a more common way to access these package files?

The view that opens and shows you the messages from *all* the newly-installed and -upgraded packages is unique to you and your particular situation - there is no way to recover it once you close the tab. However, if you're interested in a particular package's message(s), just use [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) (in ST3) to open the package, view the `messages.json` file to see which is the most recent file you want to view, then find and read that file. In ST2 all packages are already unpacked in your `Packages` folder.